# HTML dynamic cropping

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I'm currently having trouble showing images in a table.

The images all have different aspect ratios. The different aspect ratios of the images make the table of images look cluttered.

To solve this i would like to crop the part that needs cropping to have the image be exactly square. i already have the scaling down with a php script.

The tricky part is that i can only use HTML, CSS and PHP serverside, everything else is not supported.

So is there any way i can dynamically, without knowing the size of the image crop into a square?

Comment: How do you need it cropped? Center cropped? Top left cropped? Other? Posting a http://jsfiddle.net with what you have so far would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a div with specified `width` and `height` (the size of your desired square), with it's `background-image` set to the picture of unknown size centered. Then it will seem that image is "cropped", meaning everyting outside of div's size will not be visible.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options using HTML5: (you have tagged this with HTML5 so I assume you can use it)

1. You can scale up/down the image to the desired size using the image function:

```
void drawImage(Object image, float dx, float dy, [Optional] float dw, float dh);
```

Specify the required width & height and it will scale the image appropriately, although if there is too much of scaling... you'll see the obvious artifacts

Or

2 You can use another variant of the same function where you can slice part of the image defined by sx, sy, sw & sh and display at destination defined by dx, dy, dw & dh

```
void drawImage(Object image, float sx, float sy, float sw, float sh, float dx, float dy, float dw, float dh)
```